# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: ConfigParse a Path from a Ini File

Tags: python, python-3.10

I try to load a file path from a .ini file the file is in the main.py folder,
the Searche shows no solutions for filepaths and .ini files!
Or i´am to stupid to use the right words!^^ *but maybe possible*

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

parser_path = ConfigParser()
parser_path.read("ma_r_s.ini")
```

when i try this

```
FILE_PATH = Path(parser_path.get("SAVE_SPACE", "MAR1"))
```

i become the OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '"CSV_Data\\MAR1_WTlist.csv"'
```

i try the following in the .ini file like this (with r in front of the path and without)
i try backslash and frontslash in the path

```
MAR2 = "CSV_Data/MAR1_WTlist.csv"
```

```
MAR2: "CSV_Data/MAR1_WTlist.csv"
```

```
MAR2 = "full OS path to /CSV_Data/MAR1_WTlist.csv"
```

the same .ini is using to get lists and that is working well with

```
parser = ConfigParser(converters={'list': lambda x: [i.strip() for i in x.split(",")]})
parser.read("ma_r_s.ini", encoding='UTF8')
```

oh my trys can read in the problems details

Comment: You shouldn't escape slashes in the config file. ```\\``` is an invalid directory separator.

Comment: if I should omit the / how do I read a file path from an .ini, as an example (C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\My Documents)

Comment: You only need to escape backslashes in string literals, not in file contents.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it, I was a bit overzealous and put the file paths as r"home/user/CSV_Data/data.csv"
because without the "r" in the code the path is not read correctly, in the .ini it is enough Enter the path
home/user/CSV_Data/data.csv

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).